Unable to get nextjs app running in a Docker container
I'm learning next.js and have a fairly simple app (bootstrapped with create-next-app) which runs locally with npm run dev. I'm now trying to configure the app to run in a Docker container.
I've used this Vercel example as a guide and the only changes I've made to the Dockerfile (which I reproduce in full below) are:

adding ENV NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 before the npm build command because this local dev version fetches from a local API with a self-signed certificate
adding a few additional copy commands to the runner stage (honestly not sure if this is necessary or whether the standalone directory contains everything the app needs as suggested here

I've also added a next.config.js file with the following contents to force a standalone build:
module.exports = {
    output: 'standalone',
}

When I run the resultant container and browse to http://localhost:3001 I just get an empty response. However when I connect to the container's shell it appears to have all the files I'd expect (based on my limited understanding of next.js):

I notice the Vercel example uses pages whereas my app uses the app router which seems to be a new concept, but it isn't clear to me if this should necessitate a Dockerfile change.
That Dockerfile in full:
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# 1. Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm i; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi

# 2. Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
# This will do the trick, use the corresponding env file for each environment.
COPY .env.dev .env.production
ENV NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
RUN npm run build

# 3. Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/.env ./.env
COPY --from=builder /app/.env.production ./.env.production

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD HOSTNAME=localhost node server.js


In the CMD, what does setting HOSTNAME=localhost do?  As a general rule container processes must listen on 0.0.0.0 and not 127.0.0.1 and it's possible setting HOSTNAME=localhost makes the process unreachable from outside its own container.

I don't know why that's there but it's taken direct from the Vercel example I linked to. Will try without it...

Well well. Removing that fixed the issue. Thank you so much. I wonder why it was there in the Vercel example?

@DavidMaze Feel free to add this as an answer so I can accept it. Likely to help others using the Vercel examples in future.
